# DHT11 Reading Too High Values

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

When I run the program, there are no syntax errors or anything. All it does is give me values for the temperature in the hundreds. I don't know if there is a way to turn these abstract and unexpected values into the actual temperature.

I originally expected that it would print out the temperature around 20 Celsius, but instead, it prints around 600. This is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include "DHT.h"

int sensor_pin = A0; // Analog Pin sensor is connected to
int output_value ;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(5000);//Delay to let system boot
  Serial.println("DHT11 Humidity & temperature Sensor\n\n");
  delay(5000);//Wait before accessing Sensor

}//end "setup()"

void loop(){
  //Start of Program 

    output_value= analogRead(sensor_pin);

    Serial.println("temperature = ");
    Serial.println(output_value);
    Serial.println("*C");     
    if (output_value < 60) {
    Serial.println("Increase temperature by ");
    Serial.println(output_value);
    Serial.println("*C");
} else {
    Serial.println("Temperature does not need to be increased.");
}

    delay(5000);

}// end loop()
```

Comment: My bad, I did not include my code. Here it is:

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I changed that, but what should I do now

Comment: anyway, back to your problem .......... you  are not printing the temperature ..... you are printing the value that relates to the voltage at the input pin ....... the voltage goes from 0V to 3.3V (or 0V to 5V depending on the model of Arduino) ..... the reading of 0 equals 0V and maximum reading is equal to 3.3V(5V) ...... you have to refer to the sensor data sheet to determine how the reading relates to the temperature

Comment: I am giving the dht11 3.3V but I don't know how to find the sensor data sheet

Comment: if we only had a way to access vast amounts of information ..... we could find data sheets and tutorials .... hmmmm .... i wonder .......... lol ......... sorry, i could not help it

Comment: @StrawberryMilk you have a arduino uno? I'm not sure which temperature sensor you have. Can you give a link to it, or a photo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DHT11 is a **digital** device. You cannot read from it with `analogRead()`.

While temperature is an *analog* value, that's not how the DHT11 communicates with an Arduino. There is a specific digital protocol.

In your code, it appears you have added the headers for the Adafruit Sensor library and DHT library, but you never actually call the functions provided therein.

The Adafruit repository for the DHT sensor library has an example:
https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino

You can see how to create an object from the `DHT` class, and how to call it's member functions, such as `readTemperature()` and so on.